# Coloring a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I saw this question on a forum: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/19042

Given an undirected graph and a number m, determine if the graph can be colored with at most m colors such that no two adjacent vertices of the graph are colored with same color.

I am wondering if you can just compare the number of vertices to that of m,
instead of trying to find a particular solution?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a coloring even if the number of vertices (`|V|`) is bigger then `m`.

For example, in [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) - there is coloring for any `m>=2`, regardless of the number of vertices.

In a [clique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29) however, the only feasible colorings require `m >= |V|`

So:

> I am wondering if you can just compare the number of vertices to that
>   of m, instead of trying to find a particular solution?

If `m > = |V|` - there is a solution, however, **if `m < |V|` - we can derive nothing.** There might be an answer anyway.

**Bonus**: The graph coloring, for the general case is one of the classical [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np_complete) problems - meaning - there is no known polynomial solution for it, and if one can be found - we can derive `P = NP`